# NetStream FLV movie playing way too fast

Tags: flash, flv, netstream

I have this little NetStream movie (which I'm not allowed to show, sorry) set up like this:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

flv_container.attachVideo(ns);

ns.play("introMovie.flv");

ns.onStatus = function(infoObject:Object) 
{
    movieStatus = infoObject.code;

    if (movieStatus == "NetStream.Play.Stop") 
    { 
        ns.play("repeatingMovie.flv");
    }
};
```

Ok, so this actually works. **Only, Firefox** (3.6 - 10) **and Safari both play my movies way too fast!** Other browsers, like Chrome play my movie as intended. Also, this only happens on my computer.

**Does anyway know what the problem could be?**

Comment: `only happens on my computer` -- Update Flash?

Comment: Flash has been updated. Only happens on my computer in FF and Safari. Not Chrome. Chrome is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed. Adding a buffer length (any length) fixes the issue.

```
ns.bufferLength = 4;
```

Comment: You probably meant `bufferTime`, since `bufferLength` is [read-only property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bufferLength).